# REST API Files in Folders from Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am building SharePoint add-in on Office 365 based on angular JS. I followed another article here to try and read documents from a folder in a document library from the HostWeb.

here is the URL being created for the Get request

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('EverythingTechnical_id2_Documents/Projects')/files?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,FileDirRef,FileRef,FileLeafRef,FSObjType,Modified,Author/ID,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID,Author/Title&@target='https://SiteName.sharepoint.com/sites/dev'
```

and here is the response

```
Object { data: "", status: 404, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "Not Found" }
```

now I have gone over it several times and that should be OK so to check I used RESTClient in safari to do some testing and it works!

Why Do I get error 404 with Not Found in my app? Whats Not Found?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more investigating and copied a working header, then posted its url side by side and found it almost immediately, should stand out!

```
_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl
```

leading / is not supposed to be there :|-
Hope that helps someone.